# Чтения строк в файле на языке Питон

Tags: python, выборка

У меня есть лог файл путь где он лежит `/var/log/iptraf/logi`

> `Fri Mar 23 12:42:19 2012; TCP; eth0; 52 bytes; 
> Fri Mar 23 12:43:21 2012; TCP; eth0; 52 bytes; 
> Fri Mar 23 12:44:28 2012; TCP; eth0; 52 bytes; 
> Fri Mar 23 12:45:29 2012; TCP; eth0; 52 bytes;
> Fri Mar 23 12:46:30 2012; TCP; eth0; 52 bytes; 
> Fri Mar 23 12:47:31 2012; TCP; eth0; 52 bytes;`

Мне необходимо осуществить выборку из данного лога за последние две минуты и сохранить их в файл

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re, sys, datetime

cutoff = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=2)
timestr = str(cutoff)[11:19]

# Open files:
data = open('/var/log/iptraf/logi', 'r')
output = open('/var/log/iptraf/logs', 'w')
dd=data.find('timestr')
output.write("%s" %dd)
```

Но при запуске выходит ошибка

> `dd=data.find('timestr')
> AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'find'`

Как можно его оптимизировать так, чтобы он сохранял логи в путь `/var/log/iptraf/logs`
в таком виде:

> `Fri Mar 23 12:46:30 2012; TCP; eth0; 52 bytes; 
> Fri Mar 23 12:47:31 2012; TCP; eth0; 52 bytes;`

Comment: Это не вопрос, а просьба решить задачу за чужой счет!

Comment: я понимаю если бы я попросил "Напишите мне скрипт который бы сделал то то то", но ведь я выкладываю свои попытки решения, я так понимаю на то и существует данный сайт для обсуждения неправильных кодов или ходов мыслей. Я могу логически разложить задачу, но вывести ее на машинный код сложновато пока. Поэтому обращаюсь чтобы понять синтаксис написания.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если нужно получить строки новее определенного временного отрезка, то я бы сделал так:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# две минуты назад
timestamp = datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=2)

# лямбда выбирает первые 24 символа (длина даты в формате ANSI C),
# парсит дату и возвращает результат сравнения ее с timestamp
# по-хорошему, вместо %с, нужно задавать формат даты явно
is_new = lambda line: datetime.strptime(line[:24], '%c') > timestamp

with open('/var/log/iptraf/logi', 'r') as input:
    with open('/var/log/iptraf/logs', 'w') as output:

        # фильтрация только новых записей
        for line in filter(is_new, input):
            output.write(line)
```

Comment: в файл сохраняется пустой лог

Comment: Значит подстрока `timestr` отсутствует в `var/log/iptraf/logi`

Comment: логи сохраняются каждую секунду, timestr получается переменная содержащая настоящее время минус 2 минуты, т.е он там есть. У меня возник поврос пожет потому что я превратил ее в строку?timestr = str(cutoff)[11:19]

Comment: Не внимательно прочитал вопрос. Обновил ответ.

Comment: lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[:24], '%c') кстати не могу разобрать данную строчку не понятен пункт (x[:24], '%c')

Comment: [datetime.strptime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) парсит дату [в заданном формате](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) и возвращает объект datetime. А `[:24]`, соответственно, выбирает первые 24 символа из строки, т.е. в итоге для каждой строки выполняется, что-то вроде:

    'Fri Mar 23 12:42:19 2012; TCP; eth0; 52 bytes;'[:24] => 'Fri Mar 23 12:42:19 2012'
    datetime.strptime('Fri Mar 23 12:42:19 2012', '%c') => datetime object
    datetime object > timestamp => True/False

Comment: а теперь понятно. Спасибо за разжевывание. а можно будет аськой обменяться для дальнейших вопросов, если конечно есть такое желание.

Comment: Дальнейшие вопросы лучше на этом форуме задавать :)

Answer (score 1):

```
data = open('/var/log/iptraf/logi', 'r').read()
```

кроме того:

```
dd=data.find(timestr)
```